# Keyboard combinations repeat after released

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I've got a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install on a Lenovo laptop.  Often, when I tap  Ctrl + Right (to move a word at a time in a text editor), releasing the Right arrow key immediately but holding down the control key, about a second later the cursor moves on another six or eight words; sometimes it seems the cursor only stops when I release control or strike some other key.

The same thing happens with other key combinations.  It is not specific to any one program; I've configured multiple workspaces in compiz and the key combination for moving to another workspace also repeats unexpectedly.

Is this a know problem?  Is there anything I can do to fix it?